# Pandas function like SQL merge

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Is there a Pandas function like the SQL merge statement?

```
create table t(
    k number primary key, 
    v varchar2(10)
);
insert into t(k, v) values(1, 'A');
insert into t(k, v) values(2, 'B');
insert into t(k, v) values(3, null);

create table t_new(
    k number primary key, 
    v varchar2(10)
);

insert into t_new(k, v) values(1, 'P');
insert into t_new(k, v) values(4, 'Q');
insert into t_new(k, v) values(5, null);
commit;

merge into t
using t_new
on  ( t_new.k = t.k )
when not matched then insert (k, v) values (t_new.k, t_new.v)
when matched then update set t.v = t_new.v;
```

Result:

```
select k, v from t;

K   V
1   P
2   B
3   
4   Q
5
```

- Keys 1 and 3 remain unchanged.
- Key 2 gets updated from t_new.
- Keys 4 and 5 get inserted from t_new.

Answer (score 0):

Use combine_first:

```
print(df)
print(new_df)

df = new_df.combine_first(df)
print(df)
```

result:

```
     v
k
1    A
2    B
3  NaN

     v
k
1    P
4    Q
5  NaN

     v
k
1    P
2    B
3  NaN
4    Q
5  NaN
```

Discussion:

df is the original Dataframe.

new_df contains the values to be updated or inserted.

df and new_df have common index k.